# Java Web site download Cache API

Tags: java, web-applications, web, browser-cache

I am using 2 modules in my java application which downloads the same web page.
So in effect the site is downloaded twice.
In order to avoid this , is there some caching layer i can attach , so that only 1 copy of the site is actually downloaded.

I would love to see the caching at Java side , if not possible at a later level like some web caching proxy or something

Comment: When you say 'modules' are you talking about two separate executables, or just two different areas of code in the same executable?

Comment: I am speaking of 2 separate areas of code in the same executable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the two 'modules' are in the same jvm and thus can access eachothers memory, try a singleton based 'cache'.  I tend to use a HtmlSnippit cache for caching much repeated HTML snippits with great success:

```
public class Testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String html = "<div>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>";

    /* Access via the getInstance() getter */
    HtmlSnippitCache.getInstance().putSnippit("FOXY", html);

    /* Or via local var */
    HtmlSnippitCache cache = HtmlSnippitCache.getInstance();
    String moreHtml = cache.getSnippit("FOXY");

    System.out.println(moreHtml);
}

public static class HtmlSnippitCache {
    /* Singleton implementation */
    private static HtmlSnippitCache instance;

    public static HtmlSnippitCache getInstance() {
        if (HtmlSnippitCache.instance == null)
            synchronized (HtmlSnippitCache.class) {
                if (HtmlSnippitCache.instance == null)
                    HtmlSnippitCache.instance = new HtmlSnippitCache();
            }
        return HtmlSnippitCache.instance;
    }

    /* Ensure only local construction. */
    private HtmlSnippitCache() {}

    /* Clas Impl */
    private HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public boolean containsSnippit(String key) {
        return map.containsKey(key);
    }

    public String getSnippit(String key) {
        return map.get(key);
    }

    public String putSnippit(String key, String value) {
        return map.put(key, value);
    }

        public int size() {
            return map.size();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the `getSnippit()` and `putSnippit()` methods will probably need to be `synchronized` somehow for thread safety, but that's another discussion (argument?) altogether :)

(Example should run out of the box.)

Answer (score 0):

This might be slightly off-topic as this solution uses spring:

You could use the [ehcache-spring-annotations](http://code.google.com/p/ehcache-spring-annotations/) to do the caching without any code.

Essentially, you'd define a cache in ehcache.xml:

```
<ehcache>
    ...
    <cache 
       name="htmlCache" 
       maxElementsInMemory="10" 
       eternal="true" 
       overflowToDisk="false" />
</ehcache>
```

Configure to use the cache annotations in your spring application context:

```
<ehcache:annotation-driven />

<ehcache:config cache-manager="cacheManager"/>

<bean 
    id="cacheManager"    
    class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:ehcache.xml"/>
</bean>
```

And annotate your code to automatically cache:

```
@Cacheable(cacheName = "htmlCache")
public String getHtml(String url) {
    ...
}
```

This would then cache the results of the `getHtml` method based on its parameter (`url`), so on when the method is called the second time with the same `url`, the results would come straight from the cache.